# Why can't we pass parameter in eventListener's listener function?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunc(parameter1) {
    //function definition
}
document.getElementById("some Id").addEventListener("click", myFunc(myparameter));
```

Why is it that I cant pass a parameter to myFunc() function inside the eventListener? I know I can use this way -

```
document.getElementById("some Id").addEventListener("click", function() {
  myFunc(myparameter);
});
```

But why can't I do it directly ?

PS- I want to know whether the rules prescribed by W3C are to be followed directly (and I shouldn't ask this question) or is there a reason behind every rule ?

Comment: Because `myFunc(myparameter)` directly executes `myFunc` right now, not when the event is triggered.

Comment: Oh, so there is no functionality that allows me to directly pass argument, but call the function on occurence of event ?

Comment: [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myFunc(myparameter)` executes the function *right now*, not when the event is triggered. You want to pass a function which executes `myFunc` and passes the parameter when called, i.e. when the event is triggered. The most straight forward way to do that is this:

```
.addEventListener('click', function () { myFunc(myparameter); })
```

The perhaps less obvious way is [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
.addEventListener('click', myFunc.bind(null, myparameter))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your code. The `myFunc(myparameter)` executes right way. You need to call your custom function using this way:

```
document.getElementById("some Id").addEventListener("click", function () {
    myFunc(myparameter);
});
```